# li active and a hover not showing same result

Tags: html, css

I have created a navbar its `<li class="active">` is not showing desired result.

It is showing like this:[image]

I have used same css for my `.active` and `.hover`. My `.hover` is working fine but `.active` is not.

**This is Html code:**

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Servies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**and this is CSS:**

```
/*navbar css*/
.navbar{
    width: 920px;
    height: 37px;
    text-align: right;
    text-shadow:3px 2px 3px #321;
    background-color: #666633;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.navbar ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.navbar li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.navbar a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999966;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

 /*you can see here i add css for hover and active*/
.navbar a:hover, .navbar li.active{
    color: #CCCCB2;
    background-color: #999966;
}
```

[**This is its fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5mgwuvkx/1/)

#### I want to ask why they have different result even there css is same?

Comment: you want to activate the class `'active'` when in `'hover'`

Comment: Now I don't know who's answer to chose all answers are right! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `<li>` element is larger than the `<ul>` container due to padding.

Try it with `padding: 8px;`

```
.navbar a:hover, .navbar li.active{
    padding: 8px;
    color: #CCCCB2;
    background-color: #999966;
}
```

#### [Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5mgwuvkx/5/)

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are applying the active class to your li item, and not your link item. I think you will find that if you instead write

```
<li ><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
```

and your css to

```
.navbar a:hover, .navbar a.active{
color: #CCCCB2;
background-color: #999966;
}
```

[here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mgwuvkx/7/)

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have a `padding: 20px;` to .navbar li

Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5mgwuvkx/3/) or maybe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5mgwuvkx/1/).

Answer (score 0):

you have to change => `.navbar li{padding: 8px 20px;}`

or

```
 .navbar a{padding: 8px 24px;}
 .navbar li{padding: 8px 10px;}
```

Comment: The active element changes size on hover with this.

Comment: In `.navbar li` it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: It is working as I desire when i do (.navbar li:hover, .navbar li.active)

Comment: :D  . I just added more text to my answer